# Restrict a RDP connection to a user group

Tags: rdp, remote-desktop-services

Im trying to produce the following setup.
I want to have a machine running Remote Desktop Session Host accepting connections from users. The machine will have two NICs, one for admin-net and one for user-net.

As i understand, it is possible to set up a connection configuration per network adapter.

Is it possible to configure the session host to only accept users from group 1 on connection 1 and only users from group 2 on connection 2.

The goal is to only allow users from group 1 on NIC interface 1 and user from group 2 on NIC interface 2.

Comment: It sounds like you're over complicating this. You can achieve the same goal with a single NIC.

Comment: no the requirement is to separate the two nets with separate NICs. Then restricting the user so its only possible to login as admin from the admin net and user from the usernet